# Proving group objects in the category of sets are group

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I'm having difficulty proving that in the category of sets, the group objects are just groups. I know that for a category, **C** with finite products, an object,G, is a group object with the morphisms *m,e,i* where *m* is associative and *e* is the identity morphism and *i* is the inversion morphism. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should just be that given a group object in Set, if you look at what $m$ does element wise, all of the facts about $m,e,i$ should give that $m$ defines an operation on the set that makes it into a group.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that it is a group, you can simply check all the group axioms. The map $e: 1 \to G$ is just some element in $G$ since $1$ is a singleton in $\mathbf{Set}$. So we might as well denote this element by $e$ too. Then checking the axioms is pretty much direct from the commutativity of the relevant diagrams:

- **Associativity.** That $m$ is associative means that $m \circ (m \times Id_G) = m \circ (Id_G \times m)$, so we have for all $a, b, c \in G$, or equivalently $(a,b,c) \in G \times G \times G$, that
  $$
  m(m(a,b), c) = m \circ (m \times Id_G)(a,b,c) = m \circ (Id_G \times m)(a,b,c) = m(a,m(b,c)),
  $$
  and so the multiplication is associative.
- **Identity.** The category-theoretic version says $m \circ \langle Id_G, e \rangle = Id_G = m \circ \langle e, Id_G \rangle$. So for any $a \in G$ this indeed gives us
  $$
  m(a, e) = m \circ \langle Id_G, e \rangle(a) = a = m \circ \langle e, Id_G \rangle(a) = m(e, a).
  $$
- **Inverse.** Note that since we always have an arrow $G \to 1$, we can compose this with $e: 1 \to G$ to get an arrow $G \to G$ that we will also denote by $e$ (bit of abuse of notation, but it is simply the map that sends everything to the identity element). On the category-theoretic side we have this time $m \circ (Id_G \times i) \circ \Delta = e = m \circ (i \times Id_G) \circ \Delta$ where $\Delta: G \to G \times G$ is the diagonal arrow. Which for any $a \in G$ translates to
  $$
  m(a, i(a)) = m \circ (Id_G \times i)(a, a) = m \circ (Id_G \times i) \circ \Delta(a) = e,
  $$
  and
  $$
  m(i(a), a) = m \circ (i \times Id_G)(a, a) = m \circ (i \times Id_G) \circ \Delta(a) = e.
  $$

Comment: Thank you very much!